# How to create vector representation of roadmap like scans

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation

What would be the best way to create a vector representation of roadmap like scans? The goal I am trying to achieve is illustrated below. The left side represents the source image, the right side the output in the form of three vectors. The fussiness on the left is a simulation, not the actual source image:

[image]

The actual source image would look more like:

[image]

Currently I am looking at a combination of skeletonization and Hough transform. The result is rather messy though, and seems to warrant quite some extra engineering. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that my intuition was not far off. The skeletonization is a good step. The Hough transform though is not a good way to create a graph of the roadmap. It seems that the Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm can help out here. This algorithm first takes all the skeleton pixels as input, and sees this as a starting graph. The algorithm then proceeds to remove intermediary pixels that do not add information to the shape of the graph.